# Case causing weird behaviours

Tags: c

So I am decoding a message in caesar cipher without the program knowing the shift beforehand, so I am using frequency analysis to determine the shift. When I try to decode the message with uppercase letters at the beginning of every word, it outputs the correct shift, but all the uppercase letters become other letters. If all letters are lowercase, it outputs the wrong shift and the message just becomes scrambled in a different way. Sorry if you find the code a little messy.

Code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int crack(char *txt,char *alpha,int *values) {
    int txtL = strlen(txt);
    int alphaL = strlen(alpha);
    int shift = 0;
    int max = 0;
    //count frequencies of letters
    for(int i = 0; i < txtL; i++) {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < alphaL; j++)
            if(txt[i] == alpha[j]) {
                values[j] += 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    //find highest frequency letter
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    if (max < values[i]) {
      max = values[i];
            shift = i;
        }
    }
    //match highest frequency letter to e in alpha & return variable
    shift -=4;
    return shift;
}

void swap_last(char *str)
{
    //shift letters to create encoded alphabet
    const size_t len = strlen(str);
    if(len > 1)
    {
        const char   first = str[0];
        memmove(str, str + 1, len - 1);
        str[len - 1] = first;
    }
}

int main() {
    char txt[] = "shwhu slshu slfnhg d shfn ri slfnohg shsshuv";
    char alpha[] =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            char alpha2[] =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int values[26] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    printf("%i\n",crack(txt,alpha,values));
    //create encoded alphabet
    for(int i=0;i<crack(txt,alpha,values);i++) {
        swap_last(alpha2);
    }
    //match encoded message to encoded alphabet & swap encoded characters for decoded characters
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(txt); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if(txt[i] == alpha2[j]) {
                txt[i] = alpha[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `alpha` and `alpha2` be different?

Comment: alpha2 is shifted to become the encoded alphabet once the shift is found.

Comment: Looks like `crack` thinks `'s'` in `txt` is really and `'e'`.  That's not correct?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In English, `e` is the most common letter, right?  In your encrypted text, `s` is the most common letter.  Doesn't that mean `e` is the decrypted letter resulting in an offset of 14?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I figured it out. When the all of the s' are capital, it doesn't recognize them as the most common letter, therefore e becomes the most common letter & it finds the correct shift and doesn't change the s'. If it's all lowercase, then it recognizes s as the most common letter & gets the wrong shift.

Comment: @FiddlingBits in short, it doesn't recognize capitals, and the message that i picked is what's causing the error

Comment: E is the most common letter in English by far, but that doesn't mean that that is true for every sentence, especially short ones. In your example sentence, the most frequent letter is P, so your crude heuristic fails. Most Ps are at the beginning of words, so when you make these letters upper case, the most frequent letter is E.

Comment: (Observations: You probably shouldn't call `crack` in the loop condition, because it will midofy `values`. It does no harm here, but it will perform the frequency analysis `shift` times. And what happüens if the most frequent letter come before E?)